# Applying Style to Parent By Selecting Child

Tags: html, css

It appears some browsers (Chrome at least) put a partial underline under images that are nested inside of an anchor tag, like this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
```

So I'm looking for a way to add `text-decoration: none;` to any anchor tags that contain an img tag. My first thought was this:

```
a img {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Of course that doesn't work, because the style gets applied to the img tag, and not the anchor. So is there a selector I can use to apply the text-decoration style to any anchor tag with a img child?

EDIT:
My HTML typically looks like this:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="/foo.jpg" />
</a>
```

The way I space and tab the elements is adding extra whitespace between the anchor tag, and image tag. It's that white space that's being underlined.

Comment: what you are asking is a parent selector based on a child selector. That does not exit either in CSS2.1 or CSS3. You will have to apply the style by other means!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're against adding a class to this `<a>` tag (which is the simple solution), your next best CSS solution would be to remove text-decoration on the `<a>` tag, and wrap the text you want to have underlined in an inline element. See below:

For images:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="/foo.jpg" alt="etc" />
</a>
```

For text:

```
<a href="#">
  <span>Text that you probably want underlined</span>
</a>
```

Combined:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="/foo.jpg" alt="etc" /> <span>Text that you probably want underlined</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover span { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way currently of selecting the parent of an element using just CSS.

You would need to resort to javascript or jQuery.

Personally I would do something in jQuery like

```
 $('a>img').parent().addClass('noTextDecoration');
```

then in css have the following:

```
 a.noTextDecoration {test-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use

```
img {
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: That's what I always do, but in this case that doesn't work. The style "text-decoration: none;" needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, there is no way to select an element's parent in CSS. You could try applying some class, i.e. `imagelink` to A elements that contain IMG elements, though.

Answer (score 0):

If the href attribute of these anchors always points to images, and no anchors point to images besides the one with actually an `img` tag inside, then you can use:

```
a[href$=".gif"],
a[href$=".png"],
...            ,
a[href$=".jpg"] {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with cross-browser compatibility if you use this solution.